# How can I avoid repeated indices in pandas DataFrame after concat?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes and concatenate them:

```
In[55]: adict  = {'a':[0, 1]}
        bdict = {'a': [2, 3]}
        dfa = DataFrame(adict)
        dfb = DataFrame(bdict)
        dfab = pd.concat([dfa,dfb])
```

The problem is, the resulting dataframe has repeated index.

```
In [56]: dfab.head()

Out[56]:
                a
          0     0
          1     1
          0     2
          1     3
```

How can I have a single index running through the resulting dataframe, i.e.

```
In [56]: dfab.head()

Out[56]:
                a
          0     0
          1     1
          2     2
          3     3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do: `dfab = pd.concat([dfa,dfb], ignore_index=True)`